# try-catch in for loop for regressions

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch, regression

I am running a lot of regressions through this code

```
vek <- read_excel("h24.xlsx")
filterfile <- read_excel("filterfile.xlsx")

x <- c(filterfile$Column)
sink("D:/test.csv")
for (temp_var in x){
  h24 <- filter(vek,KEY == temp_var)
  h24 <- na.omit(h24)
  frml <- UNITS ~ h36+ z24+ z36+ pr
  
  if (length(unique(h24$`F`)) > 1) frml <- update.formula(frml, ~ F + .)
  if (length(unique(h24$`D`)) > 1) frml <- update.formula(frml, ~ D + .)
  
  lmtest <- lm(frml, data = h24)
  
  
print(vif(lmtest))
}
sink()
```

The `print(vif(lmtest))` throws some errors: `there are aliased coefficients in the model`

In case of these erros, I would like to run `alias(lmtest)`

Even though there are a few threads about `trycatch()` I could not fix it. What would be the easiest way to solve this?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example, so we can help you better. It's hard to code if you can't see the problem. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

`tryCatch` in R can look up to nice error handling in Python. You can try using `tryCatch` to catch the error and rerunning your code as necessary. Note that you can inspect if command returned an error and even what error exactly.

```
throwRandomError <- function(x = 0.5) {
  if (runif(1) > x) {
    stop("Random error encountered")
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

set.seed(2)
ok <- tryCatch(
  throwRandomError(x = 0.5),
  error = function(e) e
)

bad <- tryCatch(
  throwRandomError(x = 0.5),
  error = function(e) e
)

str(bad)

List of 2
 $ message: chr "Random error encountered"
 $ call   : language throwRandomError(x = 0.5)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"

# Catch any type of class, error, simpleError or condition.
# Only one is probably enough, but left here for redundancy.
if (class(bad) %in% c("error", "simpleError", "condition")) {
  print("Rerunning lmtest")
  result <- print(alias(lmtest))
}
```

You could catch specific error by using something along the lines of

```
if (bad$message == "Random error encountered") {
  print("adapting workflow")
}
```